# 9DoF IMU, Accelorometer + Gyroscope + Magnetometer, with USB connector and SDK

Tags: usb, sensor, imu

I'm searching for a device to measure orientation/trajectory in space over time. So what I need is an IMU combined with a magnetometer. Also, it should be an all-in-one solution that I can connect to my laptop via USB and use via Python or C.

When I search for such solutions, e.g. ones that include [Bosch's BNO055](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/smart-sensor-systems/bno055/), I mostly find boards like this [Adafruit 9-DOF Absolute Orientation IMU Fusion Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2472), where I'd need an Arduino and mess with the pins. Also, it wouldn't be appropriate for outdoor.

The device shall not cost more than ~ 50 EUR. 100 EUR is the absolute limit.

Comment: Someone please create tags [imu], [sensor] and edit them in.

Comment: Not gonna happen at that price point without a little soldering and programming. It's totally doable though if you can compromise on that.